# QBVideoChatController cannot be resolved?

Tags: android, eclipse, quickblox

I used **sample-videochat-android** module from [here](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android)
when I import this module in eclipse I am facing

"`The import com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.QBVideoChatController cannot be resolved` "

problem. Can anybody have any idea how can I resolved this import missing ?Or some external library dependency I have to counter ?

Answer (score -1):

This has already been fixed. Try to [download](https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-android) and use the sample once again.

Comment: Thanks for a solution but now I am facing problem "ACCEPT cannot be resolved or is not a field" in ActivityCallUser.java and "The method setCameraFrameProcess(boolean) is undefined for the type CameraView" in ActivityVideoChat.java